# Google Search Console: DNS error

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, dns

It has been 10 days since I added a new property to Google Webmaster tools. Immediately an error message was displayed: "Severe health issues are found in your property" this has since disappeared by itself. But the following errors remain:

- Site errors: "Google couldn't access your site because of a DNS error."
- Lookup error: "Your DNS server did not recognize your hostname."
- Total DNS errors: "Couldn’t communicate with the DNS server."

Google is able to fetch and render my site. The robots.txt tester shows no issues and all content is allowed. Google has also cached my site. My DNS provider says the issue is not with them. I've done a DNS health check (mxtoolbox, dnsstuff, dnscheck.pingdom, dnssy). All show no errors. I've also added a sitemap, but index status is 'Pending'.

Any suggestions? How can a new property immediately show such errors? What can I do to resolve them? Has the previous owner of the domain done something strange during their ownership?

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRpiz.jpg)

Comment: These messages do not clear up once they show up. It is just informational. Of course they will disappear eventually. It is not always an indication of an on-going problem. Cheers!!

Comment: Do you have any countries blocked from accessing your server ?

Comment: @VasilisKosmas No

Comment: Have you look out on dates? Currently google did not have any problem, checkout the last line, so just resubmit your sitemap, and it will going to work.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the dates and the graph. But I'm new to all of this so I don't understand why the error happened in the first place nor why the error persists even though the graph shows that GoogleBot has crawled my site over the past few days and found no errors. I resubmitted my sitemap yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it possible that googlebot IP address is blocked by firewall?
- Is it possible that the DNS records (Cname,A) point to a bad server IP address?

even if is a DNS error, we never know:
 - Is it possible that a php script block googlebot?

Simulate a googlebot visit using [web-sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) and choosing googlebot in drop-down menu and you will see the result

Answer (score 0):

Check or make sure of the following points:

> 1. If you have submitted in Google Webmaster Tools your domain url as **non www** like http://example.com , make sure that your **non-www** subdomain is enabled on your server for public access.
> 2. If you submitted in Google Webmaster Tools your domain url as **www** like http://www.example.com , make sure that  **www** subdomain enabled on your server for public access.
> 3. Contact your server provider and ask if they have enabled DNS Fallback for your server.

Comment: Thanks. I've done all of the above. The redirects work (www--> http) and my provider has verified all DNS settings.

Comment: "The redirects work (www--> http)" that you mentioned does not make sense, I guess you tried to described something else. Anyway, if you have submitted WWW.example.com in Google Webmaster Tools then WWW.example.com must work autonomously on your web server and not through redirection from example.com. Same applies for the vice versa scenario. Double-check it please.